# MySQL INSERT with OUTPUT like MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am pretty sure MySQL does not have the INSERT INTO table OUTPUT [column value] that MSSQL does - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx (or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/output-clause.aspx)

What's an easy way to replicate this? (I am moving a MSSQL app to MySQL. The 'OUTPUT' is a unique identifier and a int currently, so maybe I could just SELECT MAX (int) and add one, and generate a UID prior to insert?)

Thanks

Comment: Is there an AUTO_INCREMENT on the column? If yes, use `LAST_INSERT_ID`. If no, SELECT MAX will have to do, indeed...

Comment: Note that MS SQL also has a feature like `LAST_INSERT_ID()`: SET `@logSqlId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();`
You can use logSqlId as an output parameter or `SELECT` from it.
Also for future readers, consider Postgres if moving from one of the big commercial systems. Its capabilities are much closer to the high-end database systems and in some cases it surpasses them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this value is an auto-increment field, you can run `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` after running the insert, and you'll get the last value inserted into this field.
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Brilliant, haven't used MySQL much so wasn't aware of that feature, should do the trick and I can generate a GUID/unique identifier easily enough

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help at all if doing batch inserts, especially you need to do further matching up after the fact and need more than the id - resulting in an additional select.

Comment: And what if someone else inserts something between your insert and the select last insert?  Do you have to wrap it in a transaction??

Comment: @LorenPechtel No. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is local to the connection. In essence, it returns the last ID that *you* inserted, even if other connections may have inserted rows in the meantime.