# Using OUTPUT-like clause after INSERT INTO in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has `id, name ,surname` columns. When I add a new line to table, `id` increases by 1 since its `AI` and `PK`. Now how I get back latest id variable with OUTPUT command?

```
"INSERT INTO table (name, surname) VALUES ('mike', 'hensen') OUTPUT ?????? how to continue ????"
```

**edit** `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is not a very good method since in a big webpage there could be a lot adding per second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL INSERT with OUTPUT like MSSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469416/mysql-insert-with-output-like-mssql)

Comment: okay but how i am gonna echo out this value?

Comment: SELECT @yournamedvariable for example.

Comment: can you read 4th comment on your question and answer cause this is a big issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is *exactly* what you want.  It returns the last id inserted *on a per connection basis*, not the last one inserted (documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)).  Presumably, different web users would have different connections, so using the function does what you want.

If you want the last id that was inserted over all connections, but not necessarily from your most recent `insert`, then you can look at the `auto_increment` value in the metadata.

Comment: (SET @web_id = LAST_INSERT_ID());  how i am gonna echo out the web_id value in php?

Comment: @user3301042 . . . You do it with a query following the `insert`:  `select last_insert_id()`.